# Multiple roles in Asp.net MVC3

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, role

I have an admin site for the admin to create users. Here he has to chose the roles for the user - like the Asp.NET configuration site. I made 3 checkboxes with different roles.

```
[Authorize(Roles = "Admin")]
    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Register(RegisterModel model)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {

            var Rolemodel = model.RolesContainer; 
            // Attempt to register the user
            MembershipCreateStatus createStatus;
            Membership.CreateUser(model.UserName, model.Password, model.Email, null, null, true, null, out createStatus);
            if (createStatus == MembershipCreateStatus.Success)
            {
                FormsAuthentication.SetAuthCookie(model.UserName, false /* createPersistentCookie */);
                return RedirectToAction("Index", "Home");
            }
            else
            {
                ModelState.AddModelError("", ErrorCodeToString(createStatus));
            }
        }


        // If we got this far, something failed, redisplay form
        return View(model);
    }


   [Authorize(Roles = "Admin")]
    public ActionResult Register()
    {
        List<SelectListItem> tempRoles = new List<SelectListItem>();
        tempRoles.Add(new SelectListItem{ Text = "Admin", Selected = false, Value = "Admin" });
            tempRoles.Add(new SelectListItem{ Text = "Production", Selected = false, Value = "Production"});
                tempRoles.Add(new SelectListItem{ Text = "Sale", Selected = false, Value = "Sale"});

                return View(new RegisterModel { RolesContainer = tempRoles });
    }
```

----View--------

```
@{ foreach (var item in Model.RolesContainer)
               {
                    @Html.DisplayFor(m => item.Text)
                    @Html.CheckBoxFor(m => item.Selected)
               }
            }
```

When I check them and submit, I get to the breakpoint in my `Register` action, but the `RolesContainer` is null at this point - can anyone tell me why this is?

Comment: Can you show the signature of your httpost method? I think you might be expecting a parameter of a type different to the model you are passing into the view.

Comment: I updated the code now, the point is when i get to:

 if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {

            var Rolemodel = model.RolesContainer;
}
The RolesContainer is null, and not containing the chosen values

Answer (score 2):

I copied and pasted your code (except the cshtml) into the following files and it works as expected.

**HomeController.cs**

```
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Web.Mvc;
using MvcApplication1.Models;

namespace MvcApplication1.Controllers
{
    public class HomeController : Controller
    {
        //
        // GET: /Home/

        public ActionResult Index()
        {
            List<SelectListItem> tempRoles = new List<SelectListItem>();
            tempRoles.Add(new SelectListItem { Text = "Admin", 
                                               Selected = false, 
                                               Value = "Admin" });
            tempRoles.Add(new SelectListItem { Text = "Production", 
                                               Selected = false, 
                                               Value = "Production" });
            tempRoles.Add(new SelectListItem { Text = "Sale", 
                                               Selected = false, 
                                               Value = "Sale" });

            return View(new RegisterModel { RolesContainer = tempRoles });
        }

    }
}
```

**RegisterModel**

```
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;
using System.Web.Mvc;

namespace MvcApplication1.Models
{
    public class RegisterModel
    {
        [Required]
        [Display(Name = "Brugernavn")]
        public string UserName { get; set; }

        [Required]
        [DataType(DataType.EmailAddress)]
        [Display(Name = "Email adresse")]
        public string Email { get; set; }

        public List<SelectListItem> RolesContainer { get; set;}
    }
}
```

**Home/Index.cshtml**

```
@model MvcApplication1.Models.RegisterModel

@{ 
    foreach (var item in Model.RolesContainer)
    {
        @Html.DisplayFor(m => item.Text)
        @Html.CheckBoxFor(m => item.Selected)
    }
}
```

Most likely there is something wrong in your Register.cshtml file, of which we don't have to validate.

Comment: how this post action work ? can one use assign multiple roles in aspnet identity ?

Answer (score 0):

Currently when you are assigning the value to `RolesContainer` it has not been initialised. You simply need to initialise it in the constructor of your class:

```
public class RegisterModel
{
    public RegisterModel() {
        RolesContainer = new List<SelectListItem>;
    }

    // rest of your code
}
```

Alternatively you could create a constructor which accepts the `List<>` as a parameter, but the above method will work for your current code structure.

Comment: This will not solve the problem. When the CLR creates the `RegisterModel` class, the `RolesContainer` will be null, then the property will be set using the inline code to assign `RolesContainer` a valid `List<SelectListItem>` of `tempRoles`.

Comment: I updatedmy code in the post with accurate problem in comment

Answer (score 0):

If I understand well (may be I'm totally wrong), the model you post to httppost register (RegisterModel) doesn't contains the RolesContainer you expect. I think, asp.net mvc is not able to match multiple checkboxes with a `List<SelectListItem>`, a ListBox should be better

Comment: updated my code in the post with accurate problem to maybe give better understanding